# Deserialize Generic type variable as Map Key with Jackson parser

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have gone through some of the posts but not find a suitable solution to my problem.

I am trying to serialize/deserialize a `HashMap<String, Object>`. Here the value of the hash map can anything?

when I add a class called "JobData", to Map for serialize/deserialize, I am seeing some issues when I deserialize the objectMapper.

Below is the sample code

```
public class JobData {

    private FinalResult finalResult;

    public FinalResult getFinalResult(){
       return finalResult;
    }

    public void setFinalResult(FinalResult finalResult) {
       this.finalResult = finalResult;
  }
}

public class FinalResult<T> {

  private Map<T, Exception> exceptionMap;

  public HashMap<T, Exception> getFailedExceptionMap(){
     return exceptionMap;
  }

  public void setFailedExceptionMap(Map<T, Exception> map){
    exceptionMap = map;
  }
}

  Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  JobData jobdata = new JobData();
  FinalResult result = new FinalResult();

  Map<Integer, Exception> exceptionMap = new HashMap<Integer, Exception>();
  exceptionMap.put(new Integer("1233456"), new Exception("MY_ERROR", "TESTING ERROR"));
  result.setFailedExceptionMap(exceptionMap);
  exportJobdata.setFinalResult(result);

  data.put("JOB_DATA", jobdata);

  ...............

  //Serialization
  mapper.writerWithType(HashMap.class).writeValue(arg1, arg0);

  .................

  //Deserialize
  HashMap<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(in, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>()
```

Some of the links suggest to use `TypeFactory` for generic types? But not clear on how to use this?

Serialization works fine, But I am getting an error when try to deserialize

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token
>   (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain
>   As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class java.util.Map  at [Source:
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@13eb8acf; line: 1, column: 1251] (through
>   reference chain:
>   java.util.HashMap["JOB_DATA"]->com.sample.JobData["finalResult"]->com.sample.FinalResult["failedExceptionMap"])
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)

Comment: two comments - first of all, your sample code will not compile - there is no ctor for Exception which takes two String args, and the return type of `getFailedExceptionMap()` does not match the type of return value

Comment: secondly, the use of generics does not apply to all variable definitions, I mean that `JobData` class should also be parameterized with `<T>` and apply that generic parameter to all references of `FinalResult`

Comment: then, when all generic types are defined properly, it is easy to use `TypeFactory` to inform Jackson of generic types

Comment: also, which version of Jackson do you use? `writerWithType` method is Deprecated since 2.5

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used a sample scenario which explains my problem. Not really a working example. I am using Jackson 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

cannot reproduce.  This code worked flawlessly (jackson 2.8.0)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  JobData jobdata = new JobData();
  FinalResult<Integer> result = new FinalResult<>();
  Map<Integer, Exception> exceptionMap = new HashMap<Integer, Exception>();
  exceptionMap.put(new Integer("1233456"), new Exception("MY_ERROR"));
  result.setFailedExceptionMap(exceptionMap);
  jobdata.setFinalResult(result);
  data.put("JOB_DATA", jobdata);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mapper.writerFor(HashMap.class).writeValue(os, data);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
        HashMap<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>(){});
        System.out.println(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output

```
{JOB_DATA={finalResult={failedExceptionMap={1233456={cause=null, stackTrace=[{methodName=main, fileName=JSONTest.java, lineNumber=36, className=test.JSONTest, nativeMethod=false}], localizedMessage=MY_ERROR, message=MY_ERROR, suppressed=[]}}}}}
```